# Rails Faking a Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js, rails-routing

To be specific, I'm trying to get `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path` to recognize a route that is not in `routes.rb`, for testing purposes.

Is it possible to somehow mock or dynamically add a route? I'm using Rspec with Mocha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea whether will work but you could experiment with something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    # use exception.path to extract the path information
    ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
      # Add your dynamic route using path here and then do a redirect to it
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, `ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw` is what I was looking for.

Comment: `ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw` has been simplified in Rails 4 to `Rails.application.routes.draw`. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `fakeweb` gem at http://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb might fit your needs.

How to register a basic string response (from the README):

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://example.com/test1", :body => "Hello World!")
```

To test:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://example.com/test1"))
```

returns `"Hello World!"`

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://example.com/test2"))
```

In this case, FakeWeb is bypassed and the response from a real request is returned